# pgf/tikz line to triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I'm trying to draw a simple tree.

Here's the latex code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (2,-2) [circle,draw,minimum size=8mm] (A) {$\alpha$};
\node at (0,-4) [circle,draw,minimum size=8mm] (B) {$\beta$};
\node at (4,-4) (C) {};
\node at (4,-4)
[isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=+90,
draw,minimum size=8mm,minimum height=2cm,
anchor=north] (Ctriangle) {$\gamma$};
\draw [-,thick] (A) to (B);
\draw [-,thick] (A) to (C);
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's the picture:

[image]

How do I get the line to touch the top vertex of the triangle

Comment: Try `\draw [-,thick] (A) to (Ctriangle.north);` instead of `\draw [-,thick] (A) to (C);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To touch the tip, the node for C should use coordinate, so that it is a point without size, as shown below

\node[coordinate] at (4,-4) (C) {}; or \coordinate (C) at (4,-4); (Thanks to Adam)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
%
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (2,-2) [circle,draw,minimum size=8mm] (A) {$\alpha$};
\node at (0,-4) [circle,draw,minimum size=8mm] (B) {$\beta$};
\node[coordinate] at (4,-4) (C) {};
\node at (4,-4) [isosceles triangle, shape border rotate=+90,
draw,minimum size=8mm,minimum height=2cm,
anchor=north] (Ctriangle) {$\gamma$};
\draw [-,thick] (A) to (B);
\draw [-,thick] (A) to (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also just do `\coordinate (C) at (4,-4);` instead of `\node[coordinate] at (4,-4) (C) {};`.

Comment: @Adam -- You are quite right. My instinct then was to add coordinate and then fumble to test. Thanks for the sharing.

Comment: @user18048 -- Glad I can help.